# How to customize RSA Web Authentication Agent?

Tags: security, authentication, rsa

Currently in my company there's an internal web application with a custom login page. In order to authenticate the user we make use of the RSA Authentication Windows agent 7.2. We call the methods exposed by the acecln.dll library in another internal library.

Now we want to move to the RSA Authentication Web agent 7.1. I've seen how it works, I've been able to install the web agent and the protect the whole web site. By doing this, the Web agent's pages (login, succesful login) are displayed. The problem is that we still want to use our custom login web page but I haven't been able to do it.

I've checked the DLLs that come with the Web agent (rsahandler.dll and rsamodule.dll) but it seems that they're not meant to be used as the acecln.dll library in the Windows agent. What I've been able to do is to bypass the RSA Web agent's login page by making a POST request  to the handler defined in the web.config for the WebID web application set up as by the Web agent. Below are the details:

This is how the handler is defined in the C:\Program Files\RSA Security\RSAWebAgent\WebID\web.config

```
<handlers>
            <add name="RSASecurIDHandlerMapping" path="IISWebAgentIF.dll" verb="*" modules="SecurIDHandler" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\RSA Security\RSAWebAgent\WebID\rsahandler.dll" requireAccess="None" />
        </handlers>
```

and this is the form I've written in our custom login page. The   corresponds to the index.htm page that is presented after the user gets validated.

```
<form action="/WebID/IISWebAgentIF.dll" method="POST" name="transportForm">

     Username: <INPUT  id="username" style=WIDTH: 155px" maxLength=64 value="jctorres" name="username" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF"><br />

     Passcode: <INPUT ID="passcode" NAME="passcode" VALUE="1984" MAXLENGTH=16  AUTOCOMPLETE="OFF"  style="width:155px;"><br />
          <input type="hidden" name="referrer"  value="Z2FindexZ2Ehtm"> 

          <input type="hidden" name="sessionid" value="0">
          <input type="hidden" name="postdata"  value="get&#58;">
          <input type="hidden" name="authntype" value="2">
          <input type="hidden" name="stage"     value="useridandpasscode">

          <input type="hidden" name="csrftoken" value="">
          <INPUT TYPE=submit VALUE="Log In" onclick="">
     </form>
```

As I said, with this, I'm able to login with our custom login page but I'm still seeing the intermediate Authentication Succeeded that is presented before the  index.htm is presented.

My question would be:

1- How can I do to use the RSA Authentication Web agent  and still use my company own login, error web page, and without displaying the intermediate Authentication Succeeded web page? Is the behavior of the rsahandler.dll library customizable?

Thanks in advance